# Getting the session log error message in mail in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I am working in Informatica project, and we use to trigger the workflow from Autosys and if workflow fails we get the mail. After that we used to check the session log and find out the error message. Generally the error message is a Network error like failed to connect to Database. My Question is there any way to extract only the error message from the session log like "Failed to Connect to database" and send this in mail.

Comment: IU'm afraid there's no out-of-the box feature that would extract information from the log. You can either have full log attached to the email or go for a shell script that will do this for you.

Comment: We get the row level error detail in a flat file or database so I thought we might get other error detail also. Shell scripting is the last option, but if we can get this from informatica, would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... ---> Session ---> Email task

The email task will run if the session task fails.  In subject or body of email task use $PMS1.firsterrorcode.  It will then give the error code and simple reason why the session failed.  Similar to the error you see in the workflow monitor.